# Best way to integrate elasticsearch in Play framework 2.3.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, playframework-2.0

I am new in Play Framework and Elasticsearch. I want to integrate elasticsearch in my web app which I am developing in Play Framework 2.3.x. I am using MYSQL db for database, and hibernate as ORM, and as of now I have no data. We hope that data will not cross 1 million documents, in next couple of years.

I can found following 3 resources :- 
  1) ElasticSearch plugin :- https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch
  2) Elasticsearch java documentation :- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html 
  3) Jdbc River (Which as per elasticsearch statement would be deprecated.)

Please let me know what would be the best way to integrate elasticsearch ? Also if I miss anything, please advice.

Comment: Just quick concerning point 3, the JDBC river is [future proof](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#this-plugin-is-future-proof) according to its authors.

Comment: I implement ES for mongoDB using [Wabisabi](https://github.com/gphat/wabisabi) and it works fine

Comment: As per their company blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating_rivers   . Rivers are deprecating, so I want to know whether it will be advisable to use it or not. Also I am starting from scratch and I have no data to port from MySQL to elasticsearch, so I can also call elasticsearch indexing api while I save form data in MySQL. As I mentioned I don't have much knowledge about elasticsearch or playframework. Need advice about how to start integrating them.

Comment: Before moving to elasticsearch ensure that its really need or not, we will not experience the elasticsearch efficiency by just having the same data with same schema from an relational DB or NoSQL DB. So better you could reform the data from DB to elasticsearch as per your requirement. and my idea is please write your own connection method to integrate with  elasticsearch instead of search for one. Its easy and most flexible way to communicate elasticsearch.

Comment: I prefer the second one is the way to go, since first one is not active, also you need to create bean for index.